# Язык речи и звук речи

Tags: лексика

В чем заключается основная работа звуков языка?Чем отличаются звуки языка от звуков речи?Как можно обнаружить позиционное чередование звуков(примеры в разных морфемах)?

Answer (score 3):

Ну и вопросик! Вам лекцию прочитать? Разбирайтесь сами: [Язык: Фонетика и фонология](http://www.langust.ru/review/lang_h04.shtml)

Если коротко: Звуки речи - это колебания воздушной среды, вызванные органами речи.Их изучает фонетика .

А вот фонология изучает общественную, функциональную сторону звуков речи. Звуки там рассматриваются не как физическое (акустика), не как биологическое (артикуляция) явление, а как средство общения и как элемент **системы языка**.

Основное понятие в фонологии - фонема. Фонема - это звукотип, обобщенное, идеальное представление о звуке. Фонему нельзя произнести, произносятся только оттенки фонем.В слове «молоко» одна фонема **/о/** представлена тремя позиционными вариантами - ударным и двумя безударными. Фонема - общее, реально произносимый звук - частное.

**Фонема - это абстракция, тип, модель звука, а не сам звук.**

Answer (score 1):

1) Звук языка (фонема) имеет **знаковую функцию**, это элементарная знаковая частица, нижний уровень языка. Далее из фонем складываются морфемы (второй уровень), слова (третий уровень) и т.д.

2) Звуки речи - это акустическое явление. ЗВУК – это упругая волна, которая распространяется в виде  периодического сгущения и разрежения воздуха. **Звук речи является материальным носителем звука языка (фонемы).**

3) Позиционное чередование звуков происходит, когда сильная позиция звука меняется на слабую: водный - вода, образ - образовать, вратарь - аптекарь,  на стене - на ветке.